# Actionscript 3 embeded fonts UTF8

Tags: actionscript-3, utf-8, fonts, embed

I need to embed font which support all type of characters .When I do this my 'swf' file seize increase by 110kb. I want to avoid this. How this can be done without such increase in file size?

Comment: You can't have it both ways, the character data has to be stored somewhere if it's embedded. And if you are embedding the full range of utf supported characters, that's a non trivial set of characters.

Comment: @32bitkid OK If I use default font from flash would that increase file size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you need *all* characters (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters))? If so, you probably cannot avoid swf file size increase. But such a situation is very unlikely.

If you don't need all the possible characters, you can specify required character ranges either in Flash IDE or with Font metadata tag (see [this page](http://inspiritgames.com/blog/2010/09/embed-fonts-into-pure-as3-project) for an example). This can greatly reduce the file size.

At the worst, you can compile several SWFs with each having its own Unicode range embedded. And then, in runtime, you can determine which ranges are needed in a particular situation, and dynamically load the required SWFs.

Comment: Yes it`s compiling several SWFs is the solution or just using defaults fonts installed on user computer